# "Mock" a backend http response with Protractor, Cucumber and Chai

Tags: testing, mocking, cucumber, protractor, e2e-testing

First of all i will explain my goal :
I have an app divided into several modules. In this case I just want to test my ui-module.
I have some calls to the back-end there and i want to simulate the response or just change some models' values. I think you can not change the value of a model, so i am trying to simulate the back-end.

I have a model 'documents' that when i press a search button, it get data from the back-end in other module.
Example: http://localhost:8080/search-module/API/search
I want to test that without the backend.

I have tried with "httpbackend" but i can not get it going. Also i have tried "protractor-http-mock" and neither

Here is all my code for now:
[image]
[image]

I am starting with cucumber and mocking so forgive me if this question is so general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final solution for this. After 2 days of research I have everything working.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1beEchJyQejSLajJo1zqOd0gdUtaAESIqIkBXPzOs_IU/edit?usp=sharing

After try to test something with this "framework". I can say chai is not necessary. Just with Protractor-cucumber-framework and cucumber package is enough

Comment: Warning for any visitors trying to find a way to mock an angular2+ app, httpbackend just uses the addMockModule to use the angular object to mock objects. This does only work for angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [Pinch Hitter](https://github.com/stevenjackson/pinch_hitter) and [WebMock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) used for that in ruby.

If you want an out-of-process server, I have a [simulator](https://github.com/dmcnulla/simulator_baby) that will let you POST the next GET if that helps.

```
Scenario Outline: Request a special service reply for a particular path
  When I request a GET for "<response>" from "<path>"
  And I send a GET to "<path>"
  Then I receive "<response>"
Examples:
  | path   | response                        |
  | /test1 | col1,col1\nr1c1,r1c2\nr2c1,r2c2 |

@service.get
Scenario Outline: Request a service reply from a preset file
  When I have a file "<name>" with "<contents>"
  And I send a GET to "<name>"
  Then I receive "<contents>"
Examples:
  | name | contents                                |
  | temp | One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish |
```

Comment: i forgot about my app is running in Angularjs, not in ruby.

Comment: I seemed like it was JS. For my simulator, you run it separately so it is independent of whatever what code language you are using. The other two only support ruby.

Comment: thanks you @Dave but i have just resolved it. I will write and answer for people with the same problem