# mock HTTP requests of Angular2/4 using protractor/cucumber

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, http-proxy, httpbackend

I am trying to automate an angular 4 application.(protractor, cucumber, typescript). Stuck at mocking the HTTP requests.

Found Couple of approaches:

1) [httpBackend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432597/mock-a-backend-http-response-with-protractor-cucumber-and-chai)
2) [http-backend-proxy](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy)

But all of them talks about AngularJs application. And as per my understanding, they have achieved using **ngMockE2E** which I could not found in [angular2+ api doc](https://angular.io/api).

I also tried to follow [this](http://blog.ng-book.com/how-to-mock-http-requests-in-protractor/), no luck.

Can anyone help me where I can refer in order to mock HTTP calls(GET, POST, PUT etc) in my protractor project.

Thanks in advance.

@Ram Pasala, @vict: Do you have any comments!

Comment: [browser.addMockModule()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354233/protractor-mocking-backend-with-angular2-on-api-request) is not supported for AngularV2+

Comment: Have you tried using the ng-apimock plugin that comes with protractor?